# NullpointerException at startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am currently trying to implement and work with the `Google API for Java` on Android. To test things, I have been following two examples ([`CalendarSample`](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/calendar-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/android), [`TasksSample`](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java)). The code for calling the `AccountManager` and other stuff is the same as in the two examples. However, the following code does not work for me and results in a `NullPointerException`:

`startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(),2);`

I am calling this from a normal `Activity` after a button click, `onCreate` has already been called. I have tried searching Google and other sources of information for a few hours, but nothing seems to work.

Manifest:

```
<activity
android:name=".ManageAccounts"
android:label="@string/title_activity_manage_accounts"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".SettingsActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Here is the full activity:

```
public class ManageAccounts extends Activity implements GoogleLoginFragment.OnSignedIn{

DataHandler dataHandler;
//for testing of google add friend
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
Circles service;
final HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 0;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1;
static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 2;
GoogleAccountCredential credential;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_accounts);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    dataHandler = new DataHandler(this);

    //Add GoogleLoginFragment
    GoogleLoginFragment.attachToActivity(this);


    //testing of google add friend code
    GoogleAccountCredential credential =
            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(CirclesScopes.CIRCLE_ADD +" "+ CirclesScopes.CIRCLES));
    SharedPreferences settings = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
    service =
            new Circles.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Social Contacts/1.0").build();
    Log.i("Activity","onCreateDone");
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.manage_accounts, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //Request Code for Twitter button: 140
    if (requestCode == 140) {
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                haveGooglePlayServices();
            } else {
                checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
//                    AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);

            } else {
                chooseAccount();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName = data.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.commit();
//                        AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void onSignedIn(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
    GoogleSocialActions gsa = new GoogleSocialActions(googleApiClient, dataHandler, this);
    gsa.saveAuthenticatedUser();
}

/** Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date. */
private boolean checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    final int connectionStatusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
        showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(final int connectionStatusCode) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Dialog dialog =
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode, ManageAccounts.this,
                            REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}

private void haveGooglePlayServices() {
// check if there is already an account selected
    if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
// ask user to choose account
        chooseAccount();
    } else {
// load calendars
//            AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
    }
}
private void chooseAccount() {
    startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), 2);
}

public void chooser(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.chooser) {
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    }
}
```

}

Stacktrace is as following. The `NullPointer` at line 204 is the one line shown above.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3602)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4095)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17078)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4095)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17078)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.martin.contacts.ManageAccounts.chooser(ManageAccounts.java:204)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4095)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17078)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: Hi Martin, post the activity code also,from where you are starting the activity...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any intent from `credential.newChooseAccountIntent()`?? your stack traces indicates that you are not getting any intent , thus it is failing to invoke startActivityForResult().

### Updated answer

you have `GoogleAccountCredential credential;` as a instance member. But you have not initialized this member.
in your onCreate , you have declared another local `credential` but your member `credential` is never initialized properly, here is your problematic line-

```
//testing of google add friend code
    GoogleAccountCredential credential =
            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(CirclesScopes.CIRCLE_ADD +" "+ CirclesScopes.CIRCLES));
```

instead you should write only

```
    //testing of google add friend code
 credential =GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(CirclesScopes.CIRCLE_ADD +" "+ CirclesScopes.CIRCLES));
```

Comment: Currently looking into that but it seems that I am not getting any intent. Makes me wonder why...

Comment: That worked. Sometime you just don't notice and check the small things...Thanks!